# MNIST dataset:created neural network with numpy, now can't correct error about broadcasting

Tags: numpy, machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random

class Network:
    #layers, biases, weights
    def __init__(self, size):
        self.nr_layers = len(size)
        self.size = size
        self.bias = [np.random.rand(y, 1) for y in size[1:]]
        self.weights = [np.random.randn(x, y) for x, y in zip(size[1:], size[:-1])]

    def feedfoward(self, a):
        #a is activation of last layer(or input)
        for b,w in zip(self.bias, self.weights):
            a = sigmoid(np.dot(w, a) + b)
        return(a)

    def SGD(self, training_data, test_data, nr_epoch, mini_batch_size, learning_rate):
        test_data = list(test_data)
        training_data = list(training_data)
        n_test_data = len(test_data)
        n_training_data = len(training_data)
        #build mini batches
        for i in range(nr_epoch):
            random.shuffle(training_data)
            mini_batches = [training_data[j:j + mini_batch_size]
                            for j in range(0,n_training_data,mini_batch_size)]
            for mini_batch in mini_batches:
                self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, learning_rate)
            print("Epoch {} : {} / {}".format(i, self.evaluate(test_data), n_test_data))

    def update_mini_batch(self, mini_batch, learning_rate):
        bias_gradient = [np.zeros(b.shape) for b in self.bias]
        weights_gradient = [np.zeros(w.shape) for w in self.weights]
        #summing up gradients for weights and biases(calculate each gradient with backprop)
        for x, y in mini_batch:
            delta_b, delta_w = self.backprop(x, y)
            bias_gradient = [b + db for b, db in zip(bias_gradient, delta_b)]
            weights_gradient = [w + db for w, db in zip(weights_gradient, delta_w)]
        #now we update original weights and biases with gradient descent formula
        self.bias = [b - (learning_rate/len(mini_batch)) * change
                     for b, change in zip(self.bias, bias_gradient)]
        self.weights = [w - (learning_rate/len(mini_batch)) * change
                        for w, change in zip(self.weights, weights_gradient)]

    def backprop(self, x, y):
        bias_gradient = [np.zeros(bias.shape) for bias in self.bias]
        weights_gradient = [np.zeros(weights.shape) for weights in self.weights]
        activation = x
        activations = [x]
        #zs are weighted inputs
        zs = []
        #FEEDFOWARD
        for b, w in zip(self.bias, self.weights):
            z = np.dot(w, activation) + b
            zs.append(z)
            activation = sigmoid(z)
            activations.append(activation)
        #BACKWARD PASS
        #first last layer(backprop formula #1), then we assign BP3 and BP4
        delta = self.last_layer_cost(activations[-1], y) * sigmoid_derivative(zs[-1])
        bias_gradient = delta
        weights_gradient = np.dot(delta, activations[-2].transpose())
        #now we apply BP formula #2 to all others(l-2) layers, then we assign BP3 and BP4
        #first layer in this loop is last layer before output(a^L)
        for l in range(2, self.nr_layers):
            delta = np.dot(self.weights[-l + 1].transpose(), delta) * sigmoid_derivative(zs[-l])
            bias_gradient = delta
            weights_gradient = np.dot(delta, activations[-l - 1].transpose())
        return weights_gradient, weights_gradient

    def last_layer_cost(self, last_layer_activation, y):
        return(last_layer_activation - y)

    def evaluation(self, test_data):
        test_result = [(np.argmax(self.feedfoward(x), y)) for x, y in test_data]
        return sum(int(x==y) for x, y in test_result)


def sigmoid(z):
    return 1.0/(1.0 + np.exp(-z))

def sigmoid_derivative(z):
    return sigmoid(z)*(1-sigmoid(z))

import pickle
import gzip

# Next part is copied from solutions
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    """Return the MNIST data as a tuple containing the training data,
    the validation data, and the test data.
    The ``training_data`` is returned as a tuple with two entries.
    The first entry contains the actual training images.  This is a
    numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries.  Each entry is, in turn, a
    numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784
    pixels in a single MNIST image.
    The second entry in the ``training_data`` tuple is a numpy ndarray
    containing 50,000 entries.  Those entries are just the digit
    values (0...9) for the corresponding images contained in the first
    entry of the tuple.
    The ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are similar, except
    each contains only 10,000 images.
    This is a nice data format, but for use in neural networks it's
    helpful to modify the format of the ``training_data`` a little.
    That's done in the wrapper function ``load_data_wrapper()``, see
    below.
    """
    f = gzip.open('mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = pickle.load(f, encoding="latin1")
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.
    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.
    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.
    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    """Return a 10-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the jth
    position and zeroes elsewhere.  This is used to convert a digit
    (0...9) into a corresponding desired output from the neural
    network."""
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e

################################################################################

training_data, validation_data, test_data = load_data_wrapper()
net = Network([784, 30, 10])
net.SGD(training_data, test_data, 30, 10, 3.0)
```

[and this are solutions.](https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython35/blob/master/network.py). Part that is copied from solutions is [here](https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython35) in file `mnist_loader.py`.

Here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):      File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/ex.py", line 157, in <module>
    net.SGD(training_data, test_data, 30, 10, 3.0)
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/ex.py", line 29, in SGD
    self.update_mini_batch(mini_batch, learning_rate)
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/ex.py", line 39, in update_mini_batch
    weights_gradient = [w + db for w, db in zip(weights_gradient, delta_w)]
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/MachineLearning/ex.py", line 39, in <listcomp>
    weights_gradient = [w + db for w, db in zip(weights_gradient, delta_w)]
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,30) (784,)
```

I am beginner in DL and don't really know python and numpy for more than 2-3 months, but I know what's broadcasting...but I can't fix this bug anway so can pleas anyone take a look at this and suggests me how to fix it?
What's most confusing to me is that this line is identical to solutions(which work, I tried).

Oh, and short terminology remark:
nabla_b, nabla_w is bias_gradient, weights_gradient in my version

Comment: *What's most confusing to me is that this line is identical to solutions* So the problem is not this line but rather the input to this line. Apparently `w` has shape `(10, 30)` and `db` has shape `(784,)`, which cannot be added together. You should start with trying to find out where these shapes come from and which one is correct (if any). This will bring you a step closer to the cause of the error.

Comment: As far as I understand theycome from part which I copied from solutions. I don't understand this code, neither is intended to in my book. So line and where they come from are both same as in solutions, there must be something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in self.backprop the first returned variable should be bias_gradient, not weights_gradient.

Just a small hint: I think that changing batch size to something different than 10 might help to distinguish if the 10 in your error is your batch size or output layer size. I once heard, that powers of 2 are computationally efficient, but I'm not sure :)